# MKL DFT Unresolved External Symbol despite proper INCLUDE file

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I am trying to use the MKL Discrete Fourier Transform functions, I have Intel Parallel Studio XE installed with Microsoft Visual Studio, I have been using this setup for quite a while now without issue. I regularly use the MKL VSL libraries for parallel number generation and they work just fine. I am testing it by simply running the `basic_dp_real_dft_3d.f90` code which is provided in my mkl folder under `mkl/examples/examples_core_f/`. I have simply copied this code into a new Visual Studio project (Fortran console application, as I would normally) and added at the beginning

```
include `mkl_dfti.f90`
```

I have verified that this file does exist in the `mkl/include/` folder, and when I compile the code the module file is in fact compiled and shows up in the `Debug/` folder of my project. However, I get the errors

```
Severity    Code           Description  
Error       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dfti_set_value_intval referenced in function _MAIN__ 
Error       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dfti_compute_forward_dz referenced in function _MAIN__           
Error       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dfti_compute_backward_zd referenced in function _MAIN__      
Error       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dfti_create_descriptor_highd referenced in function _MAIN__          
Error       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dfti_set_value_intvec referenced in function _MAIN__ 
Error       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dfti_commit_descriptor_external referenced in function _MAIN__
```

All of these functions are defined in the `mkl_dfti.f90` module. Is there something I'm missing? I have ensured that MKL libraries are enabled in the project properties. This is normally sufficient when I use the VSL libraries, so I have no idea what the issue is at this point.

Comment: That is a linker error, not compiler error.  You must link the right libraries. Intel has a nice MKL Link Advosor, use it. I am sure this wss discussed several times before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I had enabled MKL linking in the project properties for `Release` compilation, but not for `Debug` compilation. These can be changed through the dropdown menu at the top left called `Configuration`.